# sending a object using send method in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a method which will be called when something project specific happens and then it sends out message using

```
obj.addMore(xyz);
Exchange returnExchange = producer.send(theEndpoint, new Processor() {
@Override
public void process(Exchange outExchange) throws Exception {
       ..........
       ..........
     outExchange.getIn().setBody(obj);
  }                             
});
```

This method is called 3 times and when I check what exchanges I got on the endpoint, I saw that for all 3 exchanges last state of obj is reflected. i.e.; obj (kind of array list) contains all strings added using obj.addMore(xyz);.

But my assumption is that for first exchange it should contain only one string added in first call, second exchange should contains two strings (added during first and second call) and so on.

What can be wrong and where? Or is my assumption wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each exchange is being given the same object so that when your code calls

```
obj.addMore(xyz)
```

the body of all three exchanges will update.

One way to stop this from happening would be to create a copy of obj:

```
outExchange.getIn().setBody(obj.clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the small sample of code given, it looks like you have **obj** defined as a shared instance variable outside of the **Processor** code, so a reference to the same object will be present in each exchange, which is why the body of each message will always display the same value.

If you want to ensure the body represents a particular state in time, you should create a new (or cloned) object within the **process** method each time.